# Is there a way to auto-load an image in Fantasy Grounds, upon clients connecting?

Tags: tools, fantasy-grounds

Basically, I want to leave the server on, and when clients connect, I want an image/background to load, to start setting the mood/ambiance. I will be away from my computer, so, I won't be able to manually do this every time someone connects. How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box, I don't think it is possible, google and searching Fantasy Grounds forums isn't getting an hits as far as I can see.

However if you're so inclined I do have two suggestions.

1. Create a custom theme, and distribute it to the players, so when they load up the game it will have your choosen image on the fantasy grounds desktop. A video on how to do that can be found here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQogq06PJHM&app=desktop (no personal association, nor did I watch it all the way through to see if easy to comprehend)
2. Edit the scripting files that handle everything behind the scenes. This could get crazy complicated, I've done some basic work in the scripts and it took a fair amount of trial and error, but then I'm not a LUA programmer. However https://www.fantasygrounds.com/refdoc/User.xcp suggests that there is a method for **onLogin**, which handles events to occur when someone logs in. Find that in the scripts and add in some code to share an image and that too must be in the code somewhere, as you can do that with a right-click and everything is handled by the scripts.

Comment: Option 1 is far superior IMHO. Uses built-in functionality and is far less likely to break things